# How can I authenticate an email using nodejs? I get an email for user submitted email, then I click a link on my end to verify this email

Tags: javascript, node.js

A simple web page will have email verification option where the user will enter their email. I will get an email at my address asking me to verify this email. I would then have to click a link for example in the email to authenticate them so they can use the new validated email.

Using nodejs/nodemailer whats the general direction i can go to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the standard way but one approach would be to have an endpoint (assume /verify ) in your node app to verify and the email would contain a link pointing to this.

---

To make it more clear :

As soon as user "a" registers generate a unique hash for this user .Lets assume the hash is xxx .The email would contain a link to your-app/verify/xxx and the endpoint  can handle the logic of verifying if the hash supplied and the one sent generated match . Keeping a verified flag in the db would help us keep track of the verification i.e, if the verification is successful update the db verified flag for this user.

---

Hope it helps